# Creating IHttpActionResult for returning status code Accepted

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-status-codes

I working on a demo and figuring out how to best do IHttpActionResults in the same way we got created and ok, badrequest in web api 2 right now.

```
    [Route("demosite")]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCreateDemoSite(CreateDemoSiteModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

        var identity =  CreateDemoSiteIdentity(model);
        Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);

        var taskId = Guid.NewGuid();
        _provider.SendMessageAsync(new CreateDemoSite{ TaskId = taskId, Name =model.Name, UserId = model.Email);
        _provider.SendMessageAsync(
            new UserFeedbackMessage 
            { 
                UserId = model.Email,
                JsonSerializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message ="Your site is beging created."})
            });
        return new ProcessingContentResult(this.Request, Guid.NewGuid );
    }
```

My application is going to use this approach alot that some job/task is posted and the consumer will get an accepted and will have to go to some other endpoint to get the status of his job. Therefore I wanted to create an IHttpActionResult to make this simpler for the future.

I would like to get some perspective if the idea is sound and if it makes sense the way I have done it, and if not, how to improve.

My implementation can be found below and here is the questions I have:

1. Do it make sense to return an object with the task Id and then
   set the location header for where the consumer can ask for the
   status (like the Created status code).
2. <strike>How do I set
   MediaTypeFormatter formatter for the object such it reflects what
   the consumer requested in the request.</strike>
3. Do all this make
   sense from a design point of view.

Code:

```
public class ProcessingTask
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessingContentResult : IHttpActionResult
{
    HttpRequestMessage _request;
    Guid _id;
    public ProcessingContentResult(HttpRequestMessage request, Guid id)
    {
        _id = id;
        _request = request;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage message = 
            _request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted,  
                new ProcessingTask
                    { 
                        Id = Guid.NewGuid()
                    });
        try
        {

            message.Headers.Location = new Uri("path_to_status_endpoint");
            message.RequestMessage = _request;
        }
        catch
        {
            message.Dispose();
            throw;
        }
        return Task.FromResult(message);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense. Even from a RESTful service architecture's standpoint this is a sound design - using the action you outlined, the client is creating resources of type *Demo site* by issuing `POST` to a specific URI and by returning address of the endpoint providing status of the associated task you adhere to the [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) recommendation:

> The entity returned with this response SHOULD include an indication of the request's current status and either a pointer to a status monitor or some estimate of when the user can expect the request to be fulfilled.

Comment: But I am not returning the location of the created resource! I am giving a location to another service that can give the status of the current process. Not I am returning Accepted and not Create. Your answer indicates you have read it all as it being a created status code.

Comment: I should have expressed myself more clearly, I hope it's better now.